# Java process with jemalloc on Kubernetes gets OOMKilled - how to tune jemalloc to reduce peak memory usage

Tags: jemalloc

we are using a Java process with jemalloc on Kubernetes, and occasionally the pod gets OOMKilled. Just before the kill, there is a sharp spike in memory usage and the pod gets killed. I have saved the jemalloc logs at - [HERE](https://gist.github.com/soumitra-st/40921aa952d0b0f295a5ec5208b618e3) .

My questions are:

1. How to interpret the jemalloc log to find out the amount of
   fragmentation and available space in various arenas?
2. How to limit the number of arenas and ask to unmap the mapping faster to help reduce the peak memory usage?

Thanks!